# In PL/SQL Developer 7.0, why I can't build the HTML Manuals?

Tags: html, oracle, build, plsqldeveloper

In PL/SQL Developer 7.0, I am trying to build the HTML manual with Oracle 11.2.0 or Oracle 10gr2, two problems:

1. Once I click download, the Oracle 10.2 Library link is invalid: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/database10gR2.html
2. Ok, I managed to download the 873M 10gr2 docs, 1.14G 11g docs, after building and applying, I get no response, no other tab such as "Search" etc. popped up. I used to do this in another machine, but not my new machine.

Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: PL/SQL Developer version 7?  That's pretty ancient.  Any reason why you're not using the up-to-date product?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you APC, I upgraded to PL/SQL Developer 2010, this problem does not exist! But F1 key doesn't work, however, books can be searched